# example of non compact set for rationals

Tags: real-analysis

there is an example from lectures which i do not understand.
given a closed set [0,1]  , for the below set K,  how is there not a finite subcover on K?

why is the set K=[0,1] $\bigcap \mathbb{Q}$  not compact?

Comment: Can you state what the definition of a compact set is again? That might help you already.

Comment: the compact set is closed and bounded set, then it is compact. in terms of open covers, then let the open cover exist as arbitrary unions containing K.  then a finite subcover exists for every open cover in the set.   yet the intersection with the closed interval and rationals is closed.,  and bounded....why not compact?  the set K  is the set of all rationals in the closed interval [0,1]  so i dont understand.

Comment: The set of rationals is neither open nor closed. So, your set $[0,1] \cap \mathbb{Q}$ is not closed.

Comment: You should realize that being closed is a *relative* statement, in the sense that a space is always closed *in some bigger space*. And your set $K$ is closed in $\mathbb{Q}$, but not in $\mathbb{R}$. Now note that the Heine Borel theorem only works when the bigger space is $\mathbb{R}$ (or $\mathbb{R}^n$), see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heine%E2%80%93Borel_theorem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Obverse that the cover $$[0,1]\cap \mathbb{Q} \subseteq (-1,\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}) \cup \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}}(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}+\frac{1}{n},2)$$

has no finite subcover.

Or you can use Heine-Borel Theorem.